# Use In App Purchase within Photo Editing Extension

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, photo, ios-extensions

I'm developing a Photo Editing app. There is In App Purchase (**which is working perfectly fine)** in the parent/container app.

When I'm using the extension thru iOS `Photos` app, I want to pop-up the IAP alert for the users who haven't purchased specific features. It fails to get the products from Apple server. I'm starting to think it's impossible, due to the fact it's works perfectly at the parent app.

Any insights would be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When you create an extension within Xcode, there is no ability to enable the IAP feature (entitlement) as you can for stand-alone apps. That leads me to believe that there is no support for IAP within an extension. Looking at the documentation from Apple, I didn't find specific mention of it, but noticed that there is a macro to see if API is explicitly unsupported. See: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH2-SW6

Comment: Hey Brent. Thank you for responding. So basically I need to open the Container App and execute the IAP process?